# PHP files won't run on new xampp installation

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

Apache appears to be running OK and when I go into the xampp control panel I can check phpinfo() and everything shows up just fine. When I try to open up any php files in my browser the page is blank.

Here is my Apache error log

```
[Wed Aug 29 07:07:19.160419 2012] [ssl:warn] [pid 280:tid 376] AH01873: Init: Session    Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Wed Aug 29 07:07:19.768831 2012] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 280:tid 376] AH00455: Apache/2.4.2 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.4 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Aug 29 07:07:19.768831 2012] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 280:tid 376] AH00456: Server built: May 13 2012 14:10:15
[Wed Aug 29 07:07:19.768831 2012] [core:notice] [pid 280:tid 376] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Wed Aug 29 07:07:19.768831 2012] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 280:tid 376] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 424
[Wed Aug 29 07:07:20.673648 2012] [ssl:warn] [pid 424:tid 268] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Wed Aug 29 07:07:20.767250 2012] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 424:tid 268] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Wed Aug 29 07:18:17.441000 2012] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 280:tid 376] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Wed Aug 29 07:19:34.371074 2012] [core:warn] [pid 1608:tid 376] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Wed Aug 29 07:19:35.104275 2012] [ssl:warn] [pid 1608:tid 376] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Wed Aug 29 07:19:38.193080 2012] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1608:tid 376] AH00455: Apache/2.4.2 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.4 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Aug 29 07:19:38.224280 2012] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1608:tid 376] AH00456: Server built: May 13 2012 14:10:15
[Wed Aug 29 07:19:38.224280 2012] [core:notice] [pid 1608:tid 376] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Wed Aug 29 07:19:38.317881 2012] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1608:tid 376] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 2812
[Wed Aug 29 07:19:40.221084 2012] [ssl:warn] [pid 2812:tid 268] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Wed Aug 29 07:19:40.252284 2012] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2812:tid 268] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

Comment: can you execute php in console/command?

Comment: Have you created a directory Xampp under xampp/htdocs place your file in /xampp/htdocs and type http://localhost/test.php in browser

Comment: No, but I erased the contents of the test.php file and just wrote "test" and that displays. I know it's targeting the correct file. Edit - I tried that and it didn't work either.

Comment: Display the php file there may be a error in that file

Comment: @Naveen Kumar All I have is <? echo "test"; ?>

Comment: Try `<?php echo" Test PHP Server" ?>

Comment: If you have <? as open tag you have to enable short open tags in php.ini. Otherwise you have to write <?php as opening tag. Damn linebreak splits <? and php, it has to be concatenated.

Comment: @TRD I enabled it and still nothing. Regardless, I still don't understand why nothing appears when I try to display php, but when I just have text that shows up. I figured it would display the file's content as text and not execute it. Could this be some kind of port configuration that needs to be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using Windows 7

Windows 7 has webserver which uses Port 80

so apache might not be running.
Check if port 80 is being used

To change port no of Xampp apache check this link 
[Xampp server port](http://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/07/how-to-change-xampp-server-port/)

Comment: Both ServerName and Listen are set to 80. On XAMPP control pane Apache is shown as running on Ports 80 and 443.

Comment: Check the link and change Xampp server port apache was not running properly that is why php was not executing. Change port no to 8080, then the path in browser would be `localhost:8080/`

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen to a working installation and it turned out that Skype was running and blocking the normal port I used.